# Elasticsearch get count DISTINCT users grouped by city

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index with this structure

```
...
user_id => [
    type => keyword
],
geo => [
    type => nested
    city => [
       type => keyword
    ]
    ...
]
...
```

i want to get count distinct users group by geo.city

SQL

```
select
    geo.city as user_city, count(distinct user_id) as users
from 
    `table`
group by
    user_city
order by
    users desc
```

count total returned is ok, but is not unique by user_id
i try this but count by user_id is 0

```
'aggs' => [
    'nested_geo' => [
        'nested' => [
             'path' => 'geo',
         ],
         'aggs' => [
              'group_by_city' => [
                   'terms' => [
                        'field' => 'geo.city',
                   ],
                   'aggs' => [
                        'distinct_users' => [
                             'cardinality' => [
                                  'field' => 'user_id',
                             ],
                        ],
                   ],
              ],
         ],
     ],
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED with '[reverse_nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html)'

```
'aggs' => [
    'nested_geo' => [
        'nested' => [
            'path' => 'geo',
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'group_by_city' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'geo.city',
                ],
                'aggs' => [
                    'users' => [
                        //This is added
                        'reverse_nested' => new \stdClass(),
                        'aggs' => [
                            'distinct_users' => [
                                'cardinality' => [
                                    'field' => 'user_pseudo_id',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```